# Why is it necessary to create a topic in kafka in this particular way?

Tags: apache-kafka

As the official document demonstrates, the command line for creating a topic is

```
sh /opt/client/Kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:24002 --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1 --topic order
```

but in practice, the effective command is

```
sh /opt/client/Kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:24002/kafka --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1 --topic order
```

which I should put in an additional "/kafka" to make it work.

Why does the solution that works have to include an additional "/kafka"?

Comment: You must be using a very old version; current versions don't connect to zookeeper directly; they use `--bootstrap-server kafkabroker:9092`; and the broker talks to zookeeper - for a very long time now.

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question, and no latest official documentation doesn't have this https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart